# The different frameworks around the string

Tags: string-theory, second-quantization, quantization, string-field-theory

I am studying string theory and I realize that the relations between the different frameworks are not clear to me. Following [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/685360/the-different-frameworks-around-the-point-particle), one could repeat the discussion but now taking $p=1$. We get a worldsheet, and a string that propagates in spacetime. I would now like to repeat the previous discussion but for strings.

The state of string is a point $(X^\mu(\tau,\sigma),\Pi^\mu(\tau,\sigma))$ in the phase space as before except that now position and momentum take two variables. We get what we could call the "classical mechanics of strings", or *classical string theory* (equivalent of relativistic classical mechanics but for strings). The worldvolume is now a worldsheet and can be provided with a Lorentzian metric. The interpretation of momentum and position as being field is now even easier, we call it the "worldsheet theory", it is $(1+1)$-dimensional.

We can now quantize the worldsheet theory. Position and momentum become operators and we get what we could call quantum string mechanics, but that we usually call *string theory* (equivalent of relativistic quantum mechanics but for strings).

Now, we are missing two corners of our square. Starting from classical string theory, we could "delocalize" (see previous question) and get *classical string field theory*. **What would a classical string field be ? What kind of mathematical object ?**

Furthermore, **we could quantize this classical string field theory to get *quantum string field theory*, is that right ? Does this correspond to what people call string field theory (second quantization of the string)?**

[[image: <span class=]$p=1$ square of frameworks" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJE2v.png)

In summary, I would like to clarify the relation between all those frameworks. This would also allow us to understand when we create "point particle-like" (QFT) excitations, "string-like" excitations (string field theory).

Comment: The answer is an unpleasant object : https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string+field+theory#bosonic_closed_string_field_theory

Comment: Well, "classical string fields" as analogues to classical fields are not wildly complicated: they are functionals of the worldsheet, plus ghosts to account for the necessary reparamaterisation invariance. In other words $\Psi[X(\sigma), c, \tilde c]$. The whole point is that this approach is too difficult to quantize. So we work in a slightly tweaked formalism where the string field is an element of the worldsheet CFT Hilbert space.