# D-branes mechanics and D-branes field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, second-quantization, branes

Following those two questions:

- [The different frameworks around the point particle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/685360/) (for $p=0$),
- [The different frameworks around the string](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/685364/) (for $p=1$),

I was wondering if the discussion could continue for higher $p$'s. **Could we gave D-branes field theory? And quantize that?**

Also, we now that in string theory, $D-$-branes emerge naturally, **does this means that this "square of frame works" for $p=1$ also contains all the other $p$'s?** It is clearly not the case for $p=0$ which is consistent on his own, so what is happening here?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55431